# Different segue from disclusure indicator than tapping cell in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue, cell

Is it possible to have 2 segue from a cell one from tapping cell and the other for disclosure indicator?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply, in your UITableViewDelegate

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueCellTap", sender: self)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueAccessoryButtonTap", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: I have done that but when I click on disclosure indicator it segues to same viewController

Comment: I have two segue from one tap on either cell or accessory

Comment: BTW thanks I have done that both from storyboard and tableviewDelegate thats why I had two times segue, I was performing two time, show that I had worked as well apart from storyboard in code, If I would do this I should not make segue on storyboard I guess

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating everything in a storyboard, you can simply drag from the cell (make sure the cell is selected in the outline) to the destination view controller, and do the same for the accessory.